# How to sort slice according to the numeric value and if numeric value equals then sort by alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, go, slice

I have slice as below

```
{string, int }

[{zaa 1} {aab 1} {xac 1}]
```

in this case int side equal so no I need to sort using alphabetical order

if my slice like bellow

```
[{zaa 1} {aab 4} {xac 2}]
```

I need to sort using numeric value, how can I do this?

Right now I'm using sort given by golang

```
type ByStringValue []string
type ByNumericValue []WeightBaseResourceInfo


func (a ByStringValue) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByStringValue) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByStringValue) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i] < a[j] }



func (a ByNumericValue) Len() int      { return len(a) }
func (a ByNumericValue) Swap(i, j int) { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByNumericValue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    w1 := a[i].Weight
    w2 := a[j].Weight
    return w1 > w2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type ByName []WeightBaseResourceInfo

func (a ByName) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByName) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByName) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].ResourceId < a[j].ResourceId }



func main() {

    resourceWeightInfo := make([]WeightBaseResourceInfo, 3)
    start := make([]WeightBaseResourceInfo, 3)
    var tempWeightInfo WeightBaseResourceInfo
    tempWeightInfo.ResourceId = "zaa"
    tempWeightInfo.Weight = 2
    resourceWeightInfo[0] = tempWeightInfo
    tempWeightInfo.ResourceId = "aab"
    tempWeightInfo.Weight = 5
    resourceWeightInfo[1] = tempWeightInfo
    tempWeightInfo.ResourceId = "xac"
    tempWeightInfo.Weight = 1
    resourceWeightInfo[2] = tempWeightInfo

    copy(start,resourceWeightInfo)

    fmt.Println("start", start)

    sort.Sort(ByNumericValue(resourceWeightInfo))

    if(reflect.DeepEqual(start,resourceWeightInfo)){
        sort.Sort(ByName(resourceWeightInfo))
    }
    fmt.Println("Sorted", resourceWeightInfo)

}
```

import "reflect"

Answer (score 1):

For sorting slices, simply use [`sort.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice), added in Go 1.8.

To use `sort.Slice()` you only need to provide a comparator function, which must tell if an element is less than another.

The logic inside the `less()` function should test the numbers first, if they differ, the numbers should decide the result. If they are equal, then compare the text values to tell if one is less than the other.

For example:

```
type Entry struct {
    Text   string
    Number int
}

func main() {
    es := []Entry{
        {"zaa", 1}, {"aab", 1}, {"xac", 1},
        {"zaa", 1}, {"aab", 4}, {"xac", 2},
    }

    sort.Slice(es, func(i, j int) bool {
        if a, b := es[i].Number, es[j].Number; a != b {
            return a < b
        }
        return es[i].Text < es[j].Text
    })

    fmt.Println(es)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/plwTLc2VM4)):

```
[{aab 1} {xac 1} {zaa 1} {zaa 1} {xac 2} {aab 4}]
```